# Gdrive - Need mp3 direct permanent url to play it in wordpress site

Tags: google-drive-api

I have large audio files to be played in my wordpress site. As my server being shared hosting, streaming has become much slow. I am thought of uploading the mp3 in gdrive and give the mp3 url in wordpress.

I have followed the below process-

## 1

clicked on download mp3 from gdrive, took the address, gave &type=.mp3 to the last. It worked for a day, but from next day onwards my audio doesn't play in my site. I am thinking that google is changing the url on daily basis dynamically.

## 2

thought of using the shared public link. But that takes me to google's download page. What all I need is a direct permanent link with mp3 extension for streaming purposes. This is not serving the purpose.

Any other approach in getting the permanent url with mp3 extension? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this URL ?

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=YOUR_FILE_ID
```

Check also [this page](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site) for another way; but you must use the Drive API. The idea is to use the `webViewLink` url provided by the Drive API.

Comment: Hi David, I have seen that page. But any way to get the webViewLink other than coding?

Comment: You can use the API explorer to get this without any code : https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get

Comment: HI David, I have given a file id and clicked on execute button which gave me the response in JSON format. But what use will this JSON be to me?
What all i need is a permanent link to my mp3 file in gdrive. Please help me.

Comment: The json contains a "webviewlink" attribute that you just need to copy

Comment: David, I couldn't see "webviewlink". Instead I see "webContentLink". Is this the one what you meant?
What should I do now after getting this link?
I am sorry if I am causing any inconvenience. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe. Why don't you try ?

Comment: Can you tell me what's my next step after getting this webviewlink